# c# left join whith several tables

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have two tables

Table A (2 fields. CODART and DES)
Table B (2 fields. CODART AND PREVEN)

I need to make left join with 2 tables, and return json. The table B when no have records i get this error.

((( The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. )))

i use this code

```
        var lstart = (from art in db.tableA
                      where art.CODART == 'uno'
                      join tfa in db.tableB on art.CODART equals tfa.CODART into ArtTfa from AA in ArtTfa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new 
                      {
                          art.CODART,
                          art.DES,
                          AA.PREVEN
                      });

        return Json(new { lista = lstart }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

do you know why?
Thanks.

Comment: Try System.Decimal? : The question mark allow nulls just like int?

Comment: Thanks, jdweng. You are right. I don't see it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, for my question. I found the solution.

is necesary cast the field with (Decimal?) before the field.

The new this code

```
        var lstart = (from art in db.tableA
                      where art.CODART == 'uno'
                      join tfa in db.tableB on art.CODART equals tfa.CODART into ArtTfa from AA in ArtTfa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new 
                      {
                          art.CODART,
                          art.DES,
                          (Decimal?)AA.PREVEN
                      });

        return Json(new { lista = lstart }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Thanks a lot.